# how to build an effective react native chat app with socket io and mongodb

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, react-native, socket.io

so i am building a react native chat app with socket io and mongodb
i created a socket provider and context in react native so everytime app is opened socket connection is established.
i tracked the online users through mongodb and send the message to the respective client through that online users table having socketio id
also **i am listening for messages on the message screen so how can i make the app listens for the messages in the whole app.**
i really need clues about how should i create the structure of this app so it work efficiently

Comment: did you try it? is it too slow?

Comment: no i haven't tried it....
i thought of it before implementing so i asked for expert opinion

Comment: This question is a bit too general - you are asking how to create a chat app - I would recommend you read a blog post like https://dev.to/kris/buiding-chat-app-with-react-native-and-socket-io-4p8l

Comment: that blog post is just a single screen app, and very beginner friendly so that wont help
i have many screens and need production level views

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're really asking about. Unless you have many thousands of users - and even then - nothing jumps out to me as being a bottleneck